# pgAdmin error - relation "[name of function/Views/Trigger Functions]" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm just new to pgAdmin, so I don't really know what causes these errors:

```
ERROR:  relation "ongoingprojects" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM ongoingProjects;
                      ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "ongoingprojects" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 15
```

Even if the function/view exists in the schema. Why does it give that error? And what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pay careful attention to the error message:

```
ERROR: relation "ongoingprojects" does not exist
```

Note that it is complaining about `ongoingprojects` when your SQL talks about `ongoingProjects`. You probably created the table with something like:

```
create table "ongoingProjects" ( ...
```

PostgreSQL folds all identifiers (table names, column names, ...) to lower case unless they are double quoted. Once you've created the table as `"ongoingProjects"`, you'll have to double quote the name everywhere and exactly match that case:

```
select * from "ongoingProjects";
```

The usual practice with PostgreSQL is to create tables with unquoted names in lower case with word separated using underscores:

```
create table ongoing_projects ( ...
```

so that you don't have worry about quoting.

[Here is the link to the relevant part of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was having a schema named differently than the database.

Two solutions:

1) Modify schema name to match db name

or

2) Prepend table in query with schema name, eg: `SELECT * FROM my_schema.ongoingProjects;`